# How to recover sysaux tablespace?

Tags: oracle10g, recover, tablespace

I'm using Oracle 10g and have just found out that the SYSAUX tablespace has RECOVER status.
When I check the datafile I can see that it hasn't been updated since May 2012. I understand that the core functionality in the database still is ok but have found some disturbances that I think is connected to this problem. Looking on the web i found that you can recover this tablespace: 
e.g. using RMAN:

```
connect target /
RUN {
sql "alter tablespace sysaux offline";
RESTORE TABLESPACE sysaux;;
RECOVER TABLESPACE sysaux;
SQL "alter tablespace sysaux online";
}
```

but since we are doing daily RMAN backups an this error has existed since May, is there anything in the backup that the tablespace can be recovered from?

Another site proposes:

```
SQL> set autorecovery on
SQL> recover datafile 3;
```

but how does this command recover the tablespace?

I would be grateful for some advice and apologise for my bad knowledge of this tablespace.

Regards

Tomas

Comment: Hello, I've still got this problem (I put it to rest during the summer). Isn't there anyone that can give me advice on this?

Answer (score -1):

This command does is, RMAN is taking the backup of entire database, in case some tablespace is corrupt or a data file is curroupt, using RMAN you can restore the tablespace or the datafile.

Rman doesn't restore or recover automatically, you have to define what you want to recover or restore.

Comment: The question was trying to recover sysaux tablespace